# Ext Js Combobox - Synchronous call to set value

Tags: javascript, extjs

Can't we make synchronous calls with Ext.data.Store?

I have a model which I'm loading inside a store. Later I'm binding it to a combobox. This flow works fine.

But when I want to set value of combo for default selection, I get JS error saying no elements inside the store. The reason being, the ajax call to fill the store is made after all the JS is executed. I tried making async property to false, but still no luck!!!

Here is my code snippet:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({        
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/GetAccounts',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    async: false,  //Tried this...no luck
    cache: false,
    autoLoad: true
});

var simpleCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'For ',
    renderTo: 'simpleCombo',
    displayField: AccountName,
    valueField: 'AccountId',
    store: store,
    queryMode: 'local',
    forceSelection: true
});

simpleCombo.setValue(store.getAt(0).get('AccountId')); //JS ERROR AT THIS LINE. No elements in the store
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable the combo until the store is populated. Don't mess with sync request you will freeze the whole page (or even the browser) until the requests finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I posted something similar at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12918140/1449525, but I took this kind of approach:

Add listeners to your combo box so that when the combo box is actually rendered, it should try to set its value

```javascript
listeners:{
    scope: this,
    afterRender: this.selectFirstComboItem
}
```

then add the method to your `this` (or wherever you prefer).

```javascript
selectFirstComboItem: function(combo) {
    // This will tell us if the combo box has loaded at least once
    if (typeof combo.getStore().lastOptions !== "undefined") {
        // Grab the first value from the store
        combo.setValue(combo.getStore().first().get(combo.valueField));
    }
    else {
        // When the store loads
        combo.getStore().on("load", function(store, items){
            // Grab the first item of the newly loaded data
            combo.setValue(items[0].get(combo.valueField));
        });
    }
}
```