# set combobox value based on the value of another combobox on window component extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have two comboboxes A and B and I'm trying to set the value of combobox B based on the value of combobox A in ExtJS 4. I wanna do this when the window is open and that combobox A has a value that is selected.

The comboboxes are in a form panel. I know the values that i want to set for the combobox because I load the form like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('form_panel_id').getForm().load({
    url:'request.php',
    params:
    {
        type: 'get_values', 
        record_id: 12
    },
    success:function(form, action)
    {           
        window_id.show();
        window_id.center(); 
    }
});
```

`get_values.php` returns the values (in JSON) to display in the comboboxes.

What is the best callback to achieve this and how? Sorry I'm new to ExtJS.

Thank you

Comment: You can set a `listener` to combobox A - so that when the value of combobox A is changed, the value of combobox B is updated with this value.

Comment: @TyrannicalTyrannosaurus Like I said, I want combobox B to have its value automatically because combobox A will be selected when the window is open

Comment: The second answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389128/extjs-how-to-l-set-value-for-combobox-when-loading may be helpful

Comment: Is there an onAfterLoad event for combobox or something?

Comment: Here are the docs for [afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-afterrender) and [boxready](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-boxready) which both could be helpful for your situation. For some odd reason, there is no `load` listener, but these should do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the `afterrender` event of your window and `.setValue()` combo B based on combo A's `.getValue()`

http://jsfiddle.net/urLEc/3/

Something to note, The `displayfield` and `valuefield` configs.
The `displayfield` is obviously what is shown in the combo, and `valuefield` is what you get from `.getValue()`.

If the first combos `valuefield`'s value matches the second combos `valuefield` you can can simply do:

`combo2.setValue(combo1.getValue())`